# AngularJS : Access variable outside function

Tags: angularjs

```
$scope.loadDistrict=function(id)
{

    $scope.districtList=[];
    angular.forEach($scope.districts,function(district, callback)
                    {
                        if(district.district_id==id)
                        {
                            $scope.districtList.push(district);
                            $scope.lat_wgs = district.lat_wgs;
                            $scope.long_wgs = district.long_wgs;
                            console.log($scope.lat_wgs);
                            console.log($scope.long_wgs);                  
                        }
                    })

};
```

Hello, I'm new to angular.My problem is I want to access variable `$scope.lat_wgs` and  `$scope.long_wgs` outside on this function. But when I run the code I get undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare them before the function

```
$scope.lat_wgs = '';
$scope.long_wgs = '';
$scope.loadDistrict=function(id)
{
    $scope.districtList=[];
    angular.forEach($scope.districts,function(district, callback)
            {
                if(district.district_id==id)
                {
                    $scope.districtList.push(district);
                    $scope.lat_wgs = district.lat_wgs;
                    $scope.long_wgs = district.long_wgs;
                    console.log($scope.lat_wgs);
                    console.log($scope.long_wgs);                  
                }
            })
};
```

If you declare variable inside { brackets }, value of this variable is known only inside this brackets. For example

```
foo = function(){
    var one = 1;
};
console.log(one); //oh no, i don't know what is value of 'one' variable
//well, I will output undefined
```

SOLUTION - declaring variables before { brackets }

```
var one = 1;
foo = function(){
    one = 2;
};
console.log(one); //it will output 2, cause value of variable 'one' changed 
//inside foo function, but it won't be undefined
```

Comment: i edited your code. the declaration should be outside the function ( as you says in the comment )

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice that

Comment: If i used this method, I cannot access the value of district.lat_wgs

Comment: I add this code to display the variable outside the function console.log('outside function: '+$scope.lat_wgs); . But the result is outside function: .

Comment: Maybe you don't put any value into this variable?